# Who was Naomi dancing with after the yacht sinks?

Tags: the-wolf-of-wall-street

As many of you may recall, in *The Wolf of Wall Street* the yacht sinks somewhere in the Mediterranean Sea as they are trying to reach Monaco. On the next scene, having been rescued by those Italian folks, Naomi (M. Robbie) appears dancing to [U. Tozzi's Gloria](https://youtu.be/XyduML3SNfo) theme...

Who was the girl she was dancing with supposed to be? Was she somebody traveling in the ship that rescued the crew of the Naomi or were we expected to "believe" that it was Donnie's wife?

I consider that this question is not totally out of place since we were not told whatever happened to Donnie's wife after Jordan made the captain sail to Monaco in spite of aunt Emma's sudden death in England and because Donnie's wife doesn't appear at all in the scene wherein the Naomi is about to sink...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about the girl with Naomi in [this](https://youtu.be/XyduML3SNfo?t=52) scene, right!

She is indeed Donnie Azoff's wife Hildy Azoff played by [Mackenzie Meehan](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4394776/).

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(2013_film)) says:

> Jordan, Donnie, and their wives are on a yacht trip to Italy when they
>   learn that Aunt Emma has died of a heart attack. Jordan decides to
>   travel to Switzerland immediately to settle the bank account. To
>   bypass border controls, he orders his yacht captain to sail to Monaco,
>   but the ship is capsized in a storm. After their rescue, the plane
>   sent to take them to Geneva is destroyed when a seagull flies into the
>   engine. Jordan takes this as a sign from God and decides to sober up.

As you may know The Wolf of The Wall Street is based on Jordan Belfort's memoir 'The Wolf of Wall Street' and you can relate the  characters the actors portrayed in the film [here](https://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/the-wolf-of-wall-street.php).

I believe whatever that was happening to Donnie's wife and others, was not shown in the movie as the movie largely focuses on Jordan and his way of life in telling the story. All the characters that are important to Jordan or sticks around him are focused and if you see Donnie's [character](https://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Donnie_Azoff), his wife is not that important to him now. He does not pay attention to his family any more. His wife is in the ship, but where his wife is at that moment of a disaster, maybe he doesn't even know, because Jordan is important to him. He wants to be where Jordan is, not with his wife, not with Naomi or any other. Jordan is with Naomi, that's why you see her in that scene, else you wouldn't even see her.

Comment: I am not sure. Even though the four of them were in Italy when Naomi learnt of her aunt's death, Donnie's wife could have well decided to stay there instead of making the vertursome trip to Monaco; such a possibility is vindicated but the fact that, unlike Naomi, she isn't with her husband in the control room of the Naomi when the ship sinks...

Comment: I didn't understand. You're not sure about what, that She is Donnie's wife or She was not with him when the ship sank ?

Comment: That the girl Naomi is dancing with is Donnie's wife: is Mackenzie Meehan the actress in the Gloria scene?

Comment: Well yes she is Mackenzie Meehan.
>https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4394776/mediaviewer/rm3905636352
>https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4394776/mediaviewer/rm4140517376
>https://youtu.be/XyduML3SNfo?t=78